# How to add require.js dependency to browser's developer console?

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, underscore.js

I am using developer console in my browser (Safari) for playing with JavaScript in REPL (Read–eval–print loop) sessions.

Now I want to use require.js in my JavaScript. How can I add require.js dependency to my browser so that I can play with require.js in my browser ?

For example I tried to run:

```
_.omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'userid');
```

and got this exception:

```
> _.omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'userid');
< ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _
line: 1
message: "Can't find variable: _"
stack: "eval code↵eval@[native code]↵_evaluateOn↵_evaluateAndWrap↵evaluate"
__proto__: Error
```

Surprisingly if I run the same code on the developer console which I opened in the same tab as of Underscore.js website: http://underscorejs.org website, the query runs like a charm:

```
> _.omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'userid');

< Object
age: 50
name: "moe"
__proto__: Object
```

What makes this tab special ? Is there a way to add underscore.js dependency ?

Comment: Is the underscore library loaded on the page your are inspecting?

Comment: @AlexWayne: Yep, it is! Just checked the JavaScript resources on that page!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RequireJS on the page **and** the `require` function is defined globally (e.g. You haven't "built" the javascript with r.js with `wrap` set to `true`) then you should be able to do it like this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```

Then you should be able to run any underscore function like you would normally after that. You could also do this for a one time use:

```
require('underscore').omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'userid');
```

Comment: I wan't to work with underscore in developer console of a web-browser, not on a page. How would I add RequireJS dependency to my developer console ? I got `Can't find variable: require` when I tried it.